# How do I calculate the complexity of time and memory in the bucket sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bucket-sort

All the sources on the internet give the final result and I want the calculation steps
Does anyone have any steps or resources?

Comment: Google 'Bucket Sort Alogrithm Complexity Explained' Click on any of those links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)